# libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException when load PDF on IOS Device

Tags: ios, flutter

Thread 46: "UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile() failed to allocate CGPDFContext: bounds={{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}, path=/Users/kishanvirani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B1AA298A-2DDE-46BA-9091-9D9A45F9240C/data/Containers/Data/Application/0FC5CFB0-916F-4646-9342-5A463F84F10A/Library/Caches/EasyPdfViewer/F9807771-01F9-4F15-AD56-72ABAF22414C-0.png, documentInfo=(null). Use UIGraphicsPDFRenderer to avoid this assert."

I got this error when load pdf on IOS device

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.